# channel.send is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a welcome command for my server and I have everything down apart from the bot sending the message. When I am trying to send a message with the send function, it says in the console that it does not exist. That it is not a function. I am not really sure what to do with this because I can't find anything on it anywhere.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel1 = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "welcome");
  if (!channel1) return;

  channel1.send(`Welcome to the server, ${member} \n Thank you for joining!`);
})
```

Comment: what is `member.guild.channels.cache` an array of? How was it populated?

Comment: I don't have an array set to it. Don't know if I have to set one to it.

Comment: @JaromandaX It is [populated by Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildMemberAdd). It contains [a `Collection` of `GuildChannel`s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=cache).

Comment: @TootNoot Are you sure the found channel is a `TextChannel`? (And not for instance of for example a `VoiceChannel`?)

Comment: @Ivar yeah I have no other channel named welcome so I think it found the right channel

Comment: it seems that the GuildChannel does not have a property called send, what are you trying to achieve? are you sure function should be triggered in this callback?

Comment: @TootNoot Can you run `console.log(channel1.type)` before the `send()` and see what it logs?

Comment: @Ivar it says "category" when I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) method returns a [`CategoryChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel) rather than a [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel).

A `CategoryChannel` doesn't have a `.send()` method, hence the error. You can make your `.find()` more specific to only find text channels to avoid this problem:

```
member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.type === 'text' && channel.name === "welcome");
```